# Issue with uploading project to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-sql-database

I have asp.net mvc 4 project, which working well in my local machine but when I try to upload to azure I have the following error: `Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.` Anybody know what I should to do?

P.S.: I was googling, checking connection string and no success

```
<add name="Storage_DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TechInventoryModel.csdl|res://*/TechInventoryModel.ssdl|res://*/TechInventoryModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=l90o5xco0o.database.windows.net;initial catalog=database;persist security info=True;user id=username;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Full stack trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5369905
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +124
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +167
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +66
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__1a(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext) +360
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +269
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +33
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +128
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName() +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context) +92
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +498
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateObjectContextForDdlOps() +17
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists() +36
   TechInventory.Filters.SimpleMembershipInitializer..ctor() +102

[InvalidOperationException: The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588]
   TechInventory.Filters.SimpleMembershipInitializer..ctor() +252

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   System.Threading.LazyHelpers`1.ActivatorFactorySelector() +68
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock) +106
   TechInventory.Filters.InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 nextInChain) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3b.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__35() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 nextInChain) +492
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3b.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__35() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__31(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +190
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +445
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +302
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +383
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +316
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +129
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +251
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve is following:
After 14 hours of nonstop debugging, publishing and changing project I'm comment an attribute `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` before my `AccountController` and everything deployed well into azure. I hope this was help anybody in future.

P.S.: If you don't know for what need some attributes, better don't use them.